# Tomcat: Session count. What is it?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

Okay, I think I already know, but I want to make sure, and this surprisingly simple question was surprisingly hard to google. :P

In the tomcat manager, I have some session stats, like so:

Active sessions: 1 Session count: 1 Max active sessions: 1 Rejected session creations: 0 Expired sessions: 0 Longest session alive time: 0 s Average session alive time: 0 s Processing time: 0 ms

**Is session count just the number of sessions created since the server started?**

Answer (score 5):

**Session count** is the number of current users online.

After an user leave the site the session can remain alive for next x minutes until expire.

Depend of what your reporting tool does, **Active sessions** may be the number of sessions that registered activity from users on the last 5 minutes.

Edit: the **Expired sessions** may be the number of all sessions created and expired since the server started

Comment: I'm afraid your suggestion is not right. A session is active when it has not expired yet (it is as easy as it sounds). User activity has nothing to do with this number. When a user has been inactive for the duration of the configured session alive time (30 min. default on tomcat), the session expires.

Comment: this is exactly what i said: "After an user leave the site the session can remain alive for next x minutes until expire"

Comment: I understand and you're completely right about that, but I was pointing at your next sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Active sessions: The number of currently active sessions (not expired)

Session count: The total number of sessions created since the server started.

Expired sessions: Session count - Active sessions